# I want to redefine and list of array of int64, so the values inside the arrays are sorted and only contains values which are not False

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting

I have the following data:

```
data = ['10 20 10 36 30 33 400 400 -1 -1', 
    '100 50 50 30 60 27 70 24 -2 -2 700 700', 
    '300 1000 80 21 90 18 100 15 110 12 120 9 900 900 -3 -3',
    '30 90 130 6 140 3 -4 -4 1000 1000']
data = [e.split() for e in l]
concentration = [np.array(concentration[3::2], dtype=np.int) for concentration in data]
```

I want set the values in my variable(concentration), that are not within the interval (0-50), to be False/0. So i did the following to code:

```
for row in range(len(concentration)):
    for element in range(len(concentration[row])):
        if 0 > concentration[row][element] or concentration[row][element] > 50:
        concentration[row][element] = False
        print("Error: Index {:} in time is out of range".format(element))
```

I get the following output, and my concentration variable looks like this:

```
Array of int64 [36 33 0 0]
Array of int64 [30 27 24 0 0]
Array of int64 [21 18 15 12 0 0]
Array of int64 [6 3 0 0]
```

Now i want to redefine my variable(concentration), where the values are sorted and only contain True/1 values(values which are not False/0). I want my new concentration  variable  to look like this:

```
Array of int64 [33 36]
Array of int64 [24 27 30]
Array of int64 [12 15 18 21]
Array of int64 [3 6]
```

Thanks for the help so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem using this way:

```
initial_data = ['10 20 10 36 30 33 400 400 -1 -1', 
                '100 50 50 30 60 27 70 24 -2 -2 700 700', 
                '300 1000 80 21 90 18 100 15 110 12 120 9 900 900 -3 -3',
                '30 90 130 6 140 3 -4 -4 1000 1000']

result = [sorted(filter(lambda x: 0 < x < 50, 
                        list(map(int, elem.split()))[3::2])) for elem in initial_data]

print(result)
# [[33, 36], [24, 27, 30], [9, 12, 15, 18, 21], [3, 6]]
```

If you need numpy arrays instead of lists, you can add transformation to list comprehension:

```
result = [np.array(sorted(filter(lambda x: 0 < x < 50, 
                          list(map(int, elem.split()))[3::2])), dtype=np.int) 
          for elem in initial_data]

print(result)
# [array([33, 36]), array([24, 27, 30]), array([ 9, 12, 15, 18, 21]), array([3, 6])]
```

**UPDATE**

To redefine your concentration variable with desired result you can use following construction:

```
concentration = list(map(lambda x: np.sort(x[x > 0]), concentration))
```

Comment: This is a great answer! But i still want to redefine my variable(concentration) with only my  True/0 values after my for loop, but i have utilised the "sort" method to sort my variable. Thanks so far!

Comment: @Kimdey, there's new update section in answer. Please, take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for the help Eduard! i am also trying to sort another variable in descending order, so i tried  list(map(lambda x: np.sort(x[x > 0], reverse=True), concentration)) but i keep getting an error?

Comment: @Kimdey, you can reverse order by using [::-1] construction, f.e. np.sort(x[x > 0])[::-1]

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, i actually did the following; list(map(lambda x: -np.sort(-x[x > 0]), concentration)) which also led me to an descending  order

Comment: @Kimdey glad to help! If answer was usefull for you and solve your problem, you can consider to approve it.

Comment: Eduard, could you pls, explain why and how the -np.sort(-x[ ]) method, sorts the values in descending order

Comment: @Kimdey, f.e. you have array x=[1, 3, 2, 5] -> -x is [-1, -3, -2, -5] -> np.sort(-x) is [-5, -3, -2, -1] -> -np.sort(-x) is [5, 3, 2, 1]. In result you have sorted array in descending order.